# DataGrid in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am working on a VB6 project that uses a MS Access database. I want to display the value of a column in DataGrid using the following logic:

1. 1 for a value of 1
2. 2 for a value of 2
3. 0 for other values

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the logic directly into your SQL statement using IIF statement:

```
Select IIF(YourValue < 2, YourValue, 0) as NewValue, * FROM YourTable
```

This code loads records from a `YourTable` table (please update with your table name) and applies the logic your described to the `YourValue` field (if value is smaller than 2, return 0):

```
Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sSQLStatement As String

Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

sSQLStatement = "Select IIF(YourValue < 2, YourValue, 0) as NewValue, * FROM YourTable"

objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + App.Path + "\YourDatabase.mdb"
objConnection.Open

objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objRecordset.Open sSQLStatement, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set DataGrid1.DataSource = objRecordset
```

You can add this logic to more columns, you simply need to add extra `IIF` statments to your `sSQLStatement` string:

```
Select IIF(Value1 < 2, Value1, 0) as NewValue1, IIF(Value2 < 2, Value2, 0) as NewValue2, IIF(Value3 < 2, Value3, 0) as NewValue3 FROM YourTable
```